# Use webpack to bundle doxygen html files

Tags: webpack, azure-pipelines, doxygen

I have to bundle all the files generated by Doxygen (several html pages, js scripts, svg, etc.) into one single file.

I was wondering if it is possible to do that with webpack but i don't know where to start.
I think that should be "easy" since there are not node_modules and other dependencies, only static files.

Context:
Doxygen files are stored in a zip as an Azure DevOps artifact.
I'm developing an extension to browse the generated documentation directly from DevOps, so my idea is to retreive the one single file and inject it into an iframe.

Comment: Check if [this ticket](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/17609) is helpful to you.